# create vm on opennebula with python api

Tags: python, virtual-machine, opennebula

As the title says, i am trying to create a vm on opennebula with the python api. (this is my first time working with one and i have zero clue of anythings, so plz be not too hard with me)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import oca
client = oca.Client('username:passwd', 'ip:2633/RPC2')
oca.VirtualMachine.allocate(client, 'test')
#'test' is the name of the template i want to use
```

it gives me this error:

```
 oca.exceptions.OpenNebulaException: [VirtualMachineAllocate] Error allocating a new virtual machine. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting EQUAL or EQUAL_EMPTY at line 1, columns 1:5
```

anyone an idea how to fix this? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: put your edit that answers the question as an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. i am stupid and have searched only after 4h trying in the right place --> the git repository and the 'issues' tab.

```
vm_templ = oca.VmTemplatePool(client)
vm_templ.info()

for templ in vm_templ:
    if templ.name == "Ubuntu 14.04 - KVM":
        templ.instantiate("oca-test")
```

that is a way you can create a vm of an existing template via python. 
(the connection part is missing, but that is trivial).

i don't delete this question, perhaps somebody out there will have a hard time too with this.